# calling Underscore js isEmpty on HTML object returns true in iOS8

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Can the underscore js [isEmpty](http://underscorejs.org/#isEmpty)  function be used on an HTML object?

e.g.

```
_.isEmpty(document.getElementById('myDiv'));
```

This seems to work fine desktop platforms and android devices but returns true in iOS although I know it should be false.

Is it OK to use on an HTML object or should I use another method?

**Update**:

This is the isEmpty function

```
// Is a given array, string, or object empty?
// An "empty" object has no enumerable own-properties.
 _.isEmpty = function(obj) {
    if (obj == null) return true;
    if (_.isArray(obj) || _.isString(obj)) return obj.length === 0;
    for (var key in obj) if (_.has(obj, key)) return false;
    return true;
 };
```

And it is failing on the _.has(obj, key) part which is

```
_.has = function(obj, key) {
    console.log('hasOwnProperty: obj=',obj,'key=', key, ':', hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key));
   return hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key);
}
```

For some reason in iOS8, calling hasOwnProperty on an HTML object always returns false.

e.g. output from iOS8

```
hasOwnProperty: obj= div#game-holder key= align : false
```

Any ideas?

Comment: All bets are pretty much off with native objects. When would you expect a `<div>` to claim to be empty anyway? I think you'd be better off using `_.isEmpty` for "raw" data structures and narrower specialized methods for DOM objects.

Comment: Thanks, I would not have used isEmpty myself, I am debugging someone else's code and they have used it many times. was trying to avoid having to change every instance of it's use.

Comment: Monkey patching `_.isEmpty` with your own version that does The Right Thing with DOM objects is an option if there are a lot of them to deal with and time is short.